# What is subject In the following sentence?

Tags: subjects

> Some celebrities, while commenting on this brawl, could not hide their delight at the thought of someone finally boxing sense into [Justin] Bieber"

What is the subject of *while commenting on this brawl*? Who is commenting on the brawl?

Comment: Considering that the term "boxing sense" sounds more British to me ("I'll box your ears"), I don't see how the "American English" tag applies... particularly as the subject of the sentence won't change dependent on the type of English.

Comment: FYI, in the future, most English speakers consider it obnoxious to use capital letters only in text mediums like online forums.

Comment: Some celebrities, while (they were) commenting on this brawl ... - Subject of the participle clause is "some celebrities".

Answer (score 3):

The subject is "celebrities." "While commenting on this brawl" is a parenthetical phrase. It means that it is a part of the sentence that is moved from where it normally is. Here is how the sentence is written without the phrase moved:

> Some celebrities could not hide their delight at the thought of someone finally boxing sense into Bieber while commenting on this brawl.

The reason the phrase is moved is because grammatically, the phrase should be at the end of the sentence, but in context the writer or speaker thinks that it is better for the listener to know that the celebrities are "commenting on this brawl" earlier in the sentence, so it is moved.

Comment: That was just a mild joke, but fair enough.

Comment: I got it! Thanks. By the way, in your comment,shouldn't "writter or speaker thought that it is better ...." be "writter or speaker thought that it WAS better..." or "writter or speaker THINK.."?

Comment: I think it needs tense consistence here..or am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah, I don't actually care that much about the grammar of the text that I write in the body of my answers sometimes, so I'll make mistakes. I only focus on the example sentences and giving proper examples. Tense consistency is a very common thing people make mistakes with.